# Joomla Backend Error

Tags: joomla

i have Joomla version 1.5.23 installed and the Problem is that my backend is broken. I can log in but then there is nothing more i can do there. When i click for example to edit my articles i get an error-message like this:

```
Warning: require_once(/hp/az/ab/zp/www/Joomla/administrator/libraries/joomla/template/template.functions.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /hp/az/ab/zp/www/Joomla/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php on line 354 Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/hp/az/ab/zp/www/Joomla/administrator/libraries/joomla/template/template.functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /hp/az/ab/zp/www/Joomla/libraries/joomla/application/component/model.php on line 354
```

Seems to me there's a file missing (template.function.php) but i dont have the directories the error-message tell me. so i could'nt look up if the file is missing. i found this file in an other directory and i set the rights to 777. but it did not work.
I have a second Joomla-Installation (same Version) running fine on the same server.
But the other one does'nt work. And i have no Idea how to fix this.
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: do you use default admin template?

Comment: yes, its the default admin template i use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a new site? Or an existing site that just stopped working? It would concern me if it was the latter.

If it's a new site, it's possible that not everything got moved / uploaded when installing the site. Also, you should know, the latest version in the 1.5 series is 1.5.26. I would recommend upgrading to that to see if it fixes your problem first.

You can grab the files for 1.5.26 here: http://joomlacode.org/gf/download/frsrelease/16890/73390/Joomla_1.5.26-Stable-Full_Package.zip

It shouldn't need to be said, but ALWAYS take a current backup before upgrading your site. (This is a little less important if it's a new site, but you should still, so you have a place to come back to in case something goes wrong.)

If you are using FTP, then you can just unzip the files locally, and then drop them in as a whole, it should overwrite the files that are there, and leave you custom ones in place, if you have any.

If you are SSH'd into the server, you can move the zip file to the root of your Joomla site (where the components and administrator folders are), unzip it in place and overwrite via this command:

```
unzip -o Joomla_1.5.26-Stable-Full_Package.zip
```

Comment: I want to add that in Joomla 1.5.26 neither the template.functions.php nor the call in the model is present. So updating your Joomla should indeed fix the issue for sure.

Comment: thx, for your answer. i'm talking about an existing site not a new one. Is it true that i can directly uprade from 1.5.23 to 1.5.26. At some websites the people say you first have to upgrade to 1.5.24 and than to 1.5.25 before uprading to 1.5.26. An other point is that i cant backup my Joomla-Site by using Akeeba or something else, cuz i can nothing do with my backend, every Menu-piont is broken. is it a good solution to download the whole root of my Joomla-Installation via ftp to get a valid backup ? And. will all my extension still work with the new Version 1.5.26? or are there any problems?

Comment: If you have cPanel access, you can use your file manager to create a zip of the pulic_html directory. You can upgrade directly from 1.5.23 to 1.5.26. There are no database upgrades in the interim (that I'm aware of) so a stepped out upgrade is not required. Plus, they are all just bugfix / maintenance releases, which don't break backwards compatibility.

Comment: There is a docs page explaining the upgrade process for Joomla 1.5: http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_1.5_from_an_existing_1.5x_version

Comment: ok, thanks a lot for your answers, i will try your suggestions and and leave a comment about my progress

Comment: Yes it works, i made an update to 1.5.26 and it works now, thank you so much guys

Comment: Awesome, can you upvote / mark this as the accepted answer so that future users know it worked for you?